# Alert javascript function code in alert?

Tags: javascript

i am getting script error ("SyntaxError: unterminated string literal") while showing that alert message

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<script>
var test= "<script>dsfdsf</script>";
alert(test);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

can we show script in alert ??

Comment: This is the solution:`<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<script>
var test= "<script>dsfdsf<\/script>";
alert(test);
</script>
</body>
</html>`

Comment: Or move your script to an external .js file and not have to worry about having your JavaScript conflict with your HTML.

Comment: thats working fine @nakkini wat does that mean ?? <\/script>

Comment: @karthi: it means you must escape the slash "/s" symbol, otherwise it won't worK. Please, if my answer works for you (I tested it), accept it.

Comment: u did not post it as answer. so i am unable to accept .